# Why does feature selection from SQLite attribute table fail?

Tags: qgis, sqlite

When I open a SQLite attribute table, I cannot select any features from the table. Right-clicking >"Select All Ctrl+A" and filters (queries) still work.

This method of selecting features from the attribute table works just fine for other types of spatial files.

Is this a bug, or a limitation of SQLite files? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Sounds like the table doesn't have a primary key... can you check?

Comment: No primary key. What is the quickest way to add one from within QGIS?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE SQLite_File.Table; 
ADD CONSTRAINT Table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Table);` caused the DB Manager to crash.

Comment: [Paul Lefebvre's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/25615/paul-lefebvre) comment on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631060](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631060) indicates that this is impossible.  So I guess I have to create a new table and import the existing table.  Is that correct?

Comment: You are right. And your experiment was doomed to fail, though it is not good that it leads to crash http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html.